# Git - how do you get to the files in the repository?

Tags: git

I'm starting to understand how Git saves revisions to the repository (in objects, using binary (not flat files), and with some type of SHA). But let's say you are finished with your project and you want to deploy it... Do you just make sure that your working directory is clean (by committing all) and then just take the flat files out of you working directory?, or is there some way to export the repository.  I guess that's the same as performing a checkout... Is this correct?

Comment: `git archive` does this and excludes untracked files not in .gitignore as well as .gitmodules and other possible gotchas. `git archive` was made for exactly this situation. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is handled by the command `git archive`

To get the current revision in a tar you would do `git archive HEAD > archive.tar`

Comment: Sure. `git archive HEAD > archive.tar`  I have added this example to my answer